# Highlight last data point in Scatter plot with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How can I highlight the last data point of the following dataframe in this scatter plot? Lets say I want to see it as a red point instead of blue.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=30)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(30,2) , columns=list('AB'))
df.plot(kind='scatter', y = 'A', x = 'B')
plt.show()
```

Sorry I can´t  post the chart as still haven´t  reached 10 reputation points...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way using the `matplotlib` API:

```
ax = plt.subplot()
color = ['b'] * (len(df) - 1) + ['r']
ax.scatter(df.A, df.B, color=color)
```

This will give all blue points but the last, which will be red. The array can be any length and it will cycle through the colours sequentially until all points are coloured. So, e.g., to alternate between red and blue you can just pass `['r', 'b']`. You can pass in names of colours, shorthands (as above) and colour codes like `'#eeefff'`. Check out the colour guide for more info: http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html
Another handy thing is the `s` parameter which controls the size of the dots. This follows the same rules so each dot can scaled according to an array of values.

Comment: Thanks JoeCondron, but when i run it it shows the following error:

ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'r']"
length of rgba sequence should be either 3 or 4

Comment: Apologies, I just updated the answer. The `pandas ` API is fairly limited compared with `matplotlib` as far as I can tell so when I want to do anything fancy I tend to go down that route .

Comment: Works perfect now! Thanks for the help.

Comment: just one final iteration on your answer. Just realized I don't even need to define the previous colors (If i like  the default ones) 

`color = ['b'] * (len(df) - 1) + ['r']`

Its just enough saying:

`ax = plt.subplot()`

`ax.scatter(df.ix[len(df)-1,'carry'],df.ix[len(df)-1,'vol'],color ='r')`

which would just  change the last data point.
@JoeCondron